# Mathematica implementations of classical genetic algorithm optimization

Tags: mathematical-optimization, packages, code-request

Are there any Mathematica implementations of genetic algorithm optimization routines, including third-party and commercial? (`DifferentialEvolution` isn't quite what is required.) Also, more generally, are there any Mathematica libraries/depositories?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but check this out: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1378466

Comment: Looks promising - I will.

Comment: For third-party commercial packages there is [Evolved Analytics](http://www.evolved-analytics.com/) DataModeler. It uses genetic programming (see the web site for details).

Comment: Maybe you can check out my own package `GeneticAlgorithm`. https://github.com/paulps2/Mathematica-GA

Comment: @407PZ Is this published - do you have a reference for me if I use your code and do you have benchmarks etc?

Answer (score 1):

The 'classic' text on GAs, and much more, with code, is Jacob, Illustrating Evolutionary Computation with Mathematica. https://read.amazon.com/kp/embed?asin=B00BCRB6JO&preview=newtab&linkCode=kpe&ref_=cm_sw_r_kb_dp_08NE06RNH7T0DWF35EVW